# Testing and logging "Device Offline" in react-native development environment

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm building offline capabilities for my app and having trouble figuring out how to test them properly.

I'm using the net-info library wrapped in a context to provide the app with information about the devices connection status:

```
const Connection = ({ children })=>{

    const netInfo = useNetInfo();

    const {
        isConnected,
        type,
    } = netInfo;
 

    useEffect(()=>{
        console..log(`CONNECTION ${isConnected} ${type}`);  
    },[ isConnected, type]);

    return (
        <ConnectionContext.Provider
            value={{
                online: netInfo.isConnected,
                type: netInfo.type,
            }}
        >
            { children }
        </ConnectionContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

If I manually disconnect the wifi and data, the app loses its connection to the development server and stops giving me information/logs and I can't really follow what is happening.

How do I get around this?

Comment: did you try connecting your phone with a cable or using the simulator for this?

Comment: you can show a text or button or change the style of the app depending on the device online/offline status no need to log just for test of status , if you want to log use real device connected with usb

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways to test this. The easy way and the hard way.

1. hard way, create a apk for android and drop it into your emulator to install and test.
2. Mock the isConnected variable. This will change the variable after 5 seconds, so you can see it going from online to offline.

const [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState(netInfo.isConnected);

```
const [type, setType] = useState(netInfo.type);

useEffect(()=>{
  setTimeout(()=>{
     setIsConnected(false);
  },5000);
 },[]);
```

//also need to change the arguments for the context provider from netInfo to state variables.